# Contiguos substrings efficiency

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, big-o, trie

I have the following string_='abbabbababbab'
which I want to reduce to `abb abbab2`
I have the following code:

```
def substr(string):
    j=1
    a=set()
    while True:
        for i in range(len(string)-j+1):
            a.add(string[i:i+j])
        if j==len(string):
            break
        j+=1
        #string=string[1:]
    return a

def prnt(seta):
    l=list(seta)
    l.sort(key=lambda(x):len(x))
    print l
    ## return l # if you want to return this object too
```

**Result:**

```
[['abb', 'abbab', 'abbab'], ['abbabba', 'bab', 'bab']]
```

The above code gets the job done, but time is n^2 and space is 2^n. I have seen Trie data structure but not sure how to implement this in a Trie. Is there any example or recommendation.

Comment: What is the specific rule for coming up with `abb1(abbab)2`? Why not `(abb)2(ab)2bab1`? (And why not dropping the brackets at all?)

Comment: Sorry format doesnt matter, it was just an indication of regrouping, I want to use the least number of terms/characters and abb abbab2 is the least number of terms.

Comment: `ab` is repeated `2` times too

Comment: How do you manage to use `2^n` space in `n^2` time? That would be rather impressive...